# Summarize value based on other column based on specific data range

Tags: r

I have the dataset below:

```
name<-c("John","John","John","John","John","John","John")
Dealer<-c("ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD","ASD")
Date<-c("2020-01-03","2020-01-04","2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-01-07","2020-01-08","2020-01-09")
dataset<-data.frame(name,Dealer,Date)
```

and I want to create a dataframe which summarizes by `Dealer` showing previous day number of `name` and last 7 days number of `name` based on the fact that we are in the most recent date (`"2020-01-09"`). So the new dataframe will be like:

```
Dealer2 PreviousDay PreviousWeek
     ASD           1            7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `arrange` the data based on `Date` and count number of entries we have for second last day and number of entries we have for last 7 days for each `Dealer`.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  arrange_all %>%
  group_by(Dealer) %>%
  summarise(PreviousDay = sum(Date == last(Date) - 1), 
            PreviousWeek = sum(Date %in% (last(Date) - 7) : last(Date)))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  Dealer PreviousDay PreviousWeek
#  <fct>        <int>        <int>
#1 ASD              1            7
```